# Can't come with a decent solution for a leaderboards database design

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having quite a hassle to come up with a good design for my database, i have tried 2 different examples but none of those seem to work out quite as well as had hoped.

This is the scenario i am having:

Scenario:

> A leaderboard consists out of multiple servers, a server has a name, a
>   login address and a description. A player has a name and a unique ID.
>   Different actions of the player get recorded together with *the date
>   when this action is performed* These are the actions a player can
>   perform:
>
> - He can make a kill
> - He can be killed ( a death )
> - His play time is recorded at the end of a match
> - He can win a game
>
> Per action it's date should be logged so i can get a list of his
>   statistics during the past week, past month, past year and overall.

[image]

The other solution i tried was to have a seperate kill for each table, example
table_kills
table_deaths
table_wins
table_timeplayed
players

However i would end up with a lot of tables and i dont know if its easy to implement that in code

**Update:**
Add final result (solution)
[image: The final result of my question]

Comment: Are you asking for somebody to design your database for you? That would probably be considered off-topic for Stack Overflow, I'm afraid.

Comment: The relationship of Statistic to type is the wrong way round. The diagram has 1 statistic can have many types which it plainly can't. Get that right and it's a reasonable design.

Comment: Your design looks ok to me (other than the point made by simon).  What is the problem you're having with it?

Comment: You can also consider what information you're going to need from your database when you're done with it, and work back from that. Do you just need to know how many times a player was killed? Or do you need to know who killed whom? Is play time recorded for each game, or is it a total of all a player's games? Do you need to know how many games a player didn't win?

Comment: Try creating the tables as per your diagram, and then add in demo data. I think you'll find it records what you want perfectly okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've described I would suggest tables like:

```
Servers (id,servername)
Players (id,playername,description,etc)
Actions (id, actionid, actionname, details)
PlayerActions (serverid,playerid,actionid,timestamp)
PlayerGameTime (id, serverid, playerid, timeplayed, timestamp)
```

Comment: I have made a few adjustments, i have added a field playergame_id to table PlayerActions, and i removed the serverid in PlayerActions, that way it also allows me to get a list of actions a player performed during a specific game :)

Comment: @MaximGeerinck that looks like it would work fine, so long as you don't care what server a certain game happened on (i.e. there are just a pool of servers and you don't have a ranking per server)

Answer (score 0):

You can have these tables (assuming you have a Players table):

```
  Kills
 | killed_player_id | killer_player_id | game_id | time_of_kill
 | 2                | 4                | 1       | 12-14-2013 02:14:24 AM
 | 4                | 2                | 1       | 12-14-2013 02:15:00 AM

  Games
 | game_id | winner_player_id | length_of_game |
 | 1       | 4                | 141245         |
 | 2       | 3                | 258881         |
```

Then with these schemas you can easily find how many kills per user per game, who won the game, how long the game was, etc.

Of course, this is all **very simplified**. You may need more tables and more rows in these tables.

### UPDATE

You won't need a Deaths table if you have a Kills table because you can keep track of who killed who and who killed.

```
SELECT p.Name, COUNT(k.id) as DEATHS
FROM Players p
JOIN Kills k on k.killed_player_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 3
GROUP ON k.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i did like it however i think the one from Digital chris suits best for me.

Comment: But, I am a digital Chris, too! :)

Comment: @ChrisLava Hey hey now. There can be only one.

Comment: @DigitalChris obviously not! Though I suppose we can learn to co-exist peacefully on this site, as long as we take care to not step on each other's toes again. :)